# jQuery keyup() and Chinese/Japanese/Korean Input

Tags: jquery, cjk, keyup

I'm using a keyup() event on a textbox, which sends an AJAX request to a php file. The input is usually in Chinese/Korean/Japanese text. The problem is that the IME for these languages is based on Latin, then you press a number, and it converts it to the character. E.g.,

[image]

Even though the Latin doesn't show up in the textbox at all, each letter is sent as an AJAX request, so it must be there but "invisible" or something. For example, if I type "ni hao", the following are sent as requests:

1. n
2. ni
3. ni h
4. ni ha
5. ni hao
6. 你好

Even though **only** 你好 is ever shown in the textbox. This results in so many wasted AJAX queries, so how would I go about limiting the queries to the **chinese characters only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really inelegant, but maybe you could check the last inputted character's character code and see if it is higher than the character code for English characters (usually 60-100):

```
 $('textarea').on('keyup',function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val(),
        length = value.length,
        lastChar = value.substring(length-1, length),
        charCode = lastChar.charCodeAt(0);

    if (charCode > 200) {
        // $.ajax()  
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: This will only work if the newly entered character is the last in the sequence.